# What could be the meaning of "a door was opened" for him in 2 Corinthians 2:12?

Tags: 2-corinthians

2 Corinthians 2:12 (KJV)

> 12 Furthermore, when I came to Troas to preach Christ's gospel, and ***a door was opened*** unto me of the Lord, 13 I had no rest in my spirit, because I found not Titus my brother:  but taking my leave of them, I went from thence into Macedonia.

Why did Paul leave Troas when the door to preach the gospel of Christ had been opened for him or he meant something else by the door being opened?

Comment: In its current form, this question is opinion-based and is not a good fit for BH.SE, and is likely to be Closed. Perhaps you should re-word the title to make it clear you're asking whether there could be any other meaning to "a door was opened", since we can't really speculate on Paul's motivations.

Answer (score 1):

What Paul means here is that although the *door was opened to preach Christ's gospel* in Troas, he could not stay and do so because the ministry was too much for him alone without the support of Titus.

This is the same interpretation given by Chrysostom (4th century) in his [*Homily V* of on this Epistle](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf112.v.v.html):

> ‘I spent no longer time, being straitened and distressed.’ And perhaps
>   the work was even impeded by his absence. And this was no light
>   consolation to them too. For if when a door was opened there, and for
>   this purpose he had come; yet because he found not the brother, he
>   quickly started away; much more, he saith, ought ye to make allowance
>   for the compulsion of those affairs which lead us and lead us about
>   everywhere, and suffer us not according as we desire either to
>   journey, or to tarry longer amongst those with whom we may wish to
>   remain.